# Java rest app does not create database with SQLite

Tags: java, database, sqlite, rest

I am new to java rest applications and I am trying to create an app to store books. I decided to store the information in a SQLite database, but the code is not creating the database.

This is the code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String insertarLibro(libro anadir) {
    $anadirLibro(anadir.getNombreLibro(), anadir.getNombreAutor());
    return "Libro posiblemente anadido ";
}

public boolean $anadirLibro(String libro, String autor){
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    boolean creado=false;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + this.getClass().getResource("/").getPath() + "/libreria.db");

        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LIBRERIA " +
                   "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT," +
                   " LIBRO          TEXT    NOT NULL, " + 
                   " AUTOR            TEXT     NOT NULL)"; 
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO LIBRERIA (ID, LIBRO,AUTOR) " +
              "VALUES ('1', 'ejemplo', 'ejemplo');";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        stmt = c.createStatement();
        sql = "INSERT INTO LIBRERIA (LIBRO, AUTOR) " +
              "VALUES ('"+libro+"', '"+autor+"');"; 
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("EL LIBRO SE DEBERIA DE AÑADIR: " + c);
        creado=true;
        stmt.close();
        c.close();

    } catch (Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return creado;
}
```

Comment: You should be using `PreparedStatement`. There's almost no reason to ever use a regular `Statement` when using `JDBC` directly. It's also bad to use `System.exit()`.

Comment: With PreparedStatement my code does not work. The thing is that if I create a project only with the SQLite part it works, but if I try to use SQLite with java rest it does not work

Comment: You have many issues in your code that aren't related to the specific issue you are having... such as what I pointed out above. Your formatting makes things difficult to read as well, and you should not use `$` in front of method names. While the formatting and `$` are conventions, the other things I pointed out are best practices.

Comment: Also, nobody has any idea what "it does not work" means. Surely you get a stacktrace that tells you exactly what's happening.

Comment: When I say "it does not work" I mean that if I make a Java project only with the function that creates the database and insert the values my code works, but if I use the same function in a java web project for rest services, the code dont create the database. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You're going to need to troubleshoot to find where it's not doing what you expect. Sounds to me like it's not invoking your method at all... so, you need to find out why. It could be a huge number of things, and you've not provided enough information to determine why. Perhaps your controller isn't setup properly... perhaps you typed the wrong method somewhere, perhaps it's throwing a stack trace somewhere, etc. You're question is "it's not creating the database", but it seems you're real problem isn't SQLite related at all... rather, it's your controller.

Comment: I would recommend opening a new question and showing us your controller code, as well as the above code, in addition to any stack traces it may produce during runtime, and/or any logs/print statements it generates.